# SMS доступ к элементам сайта

Tags: php, sms

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть сайт, на котором есть N элементов, стоимость каждого, допустим, 10 рублей.
Как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь хотел что-л. купить, ему на телефон приходило SMS с паролем доступа(пароль должен все время меняться), как в интернет-магазине с оплатой по телефону.
Слышал, что можно сделать почтовый ящик, на который отсылается письмо, которое потом сразу же пересылается на SMS.

Спасибо...

Comment: Как-то не понятно занят вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть специальные сервисы, естественно не бесплатные.
При получении короткого номера в таких сервисах, поддержка объяснить вам как вам реализовать соединение вашего скрипта с сервисом.

Comment: Благодарю, а можете показать такие сервисы?

Comment: Не реклама: http://smscoin.com/info/services/

Answer (score 1):

Здесь могут быть две связанные задачи: оплата по SMS (то есть через телефонный счет пользователя) и оплата своими средствами (Яндекс.Деньги и т.п. ) и доставка ключа по SMS. В первом случае используются службы типа [smscoin](http://smscoin.com/), во втором - типа [smsc](http://smsc.ru/). Почитать: [Как отправлять уведомления с сайта по SMS?](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/47794/)